# Data are adding in default channel in hyperledger fabric

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-composer

I have setup blockchain business network using composer cli and i have created total 8 channels and 8 peers one per each channel.But now when i add asset in blockchain the transaction is stored in default channel that is first channel i am also connecting to antoher channel using fabric client but then also it is saved in default channel.So please tell me how can i add asset in different channel.

In this code i am connecting to different channel using fabric client but then also when i add asset it's transaction is reflected in default first channel.This is the thing i am not able to understand

```
           channelConnection.channelConnect('channelplanfumigacion', 
          'peer1.org1.fumigacion.com').then(async (channelConnect) => {
            let idFito = uuid();
            let auditorData = {
                idFito: idFito.toString(),
                realDate: new Date(data.realDate),
                hrInitial: data.hrInitial,
                hrFinal: data.hrFinal,
                wind: data.wind,
                observation: data.observation,
                auditor: data.auditorId.toString()
            };

            let factory = businessNetworkConnection.getBusinessNetwork().getFactory();
            let assetRegistry = await businessNetworkConnection.getAssetRegistry(`${config.ns}.${assetType}`);
            let ownerRelations = factory.newRelationship(config.ns, 'Auditor', data.auditorId);
            let resource = factory.newResource(config.ns, assetType, idFito);
            // resource.owner = ownerRelations;
            //  newDocument = Object.assign(newDocument, documentData);
            delete auditorData.auditor;
            resource.auditor = ownerRelations
            resource = Object.assign(resource, auditorData);
            let assetAdded = await assetRegistry.add(resource);
        })
```

Comment: Are you passing the respected peer of the targeted channel? In your code it is peer1, when you're are passing a channel to this peer to which it didn't join, it may be using the channel it joined. Try to pass the respected peer of the channel.

Comment: @ShubhamChadokar Hey do you have idea about how can i connect 2 business network cards in hyperledger composer simultaneously in Node.js

Comment: I don't work on Composer. My suggestion for you also to start working on fabric sdk. Read the message from the composer community. They stopped the project.  https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/blob/master/README.md

Comment: @ShubhamChadokar ok so can you tell me how we can insert data in blocks on channel using fabric sdk. I mean what is the function name to do this thing.

Comment: Read the fabric sample's balance transfer. It will be a good guide for you. Invoke is the method which will run the chaincode's write function, this will add the transaction in the block. Query method runs the chaincode's read function.